# String concatenation in custom DBMS producing strange results

Tags: concatenation, database

When trying a simple `CONCAT` I am getting syntax errors. The connection uses a proprietary ODBC driver, which I'm sure is the issue, but want to know if there is anything I can do from my end. The following is the query I initially tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DF', '01', ServiceCode) AS RecordID
FROM ServiceCodes
```

However this throws a syntax error near `, ServiceCode`, no other information. So I tried:

```
SELECT 'DF' + '01' + ServiceCode AS RecordID
FROM ServiceCodes
```

But this returns the error `term_expr type not supported` which I assume is a specific error from the driver.

So then I tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('DF', '01'), ServiceCode) AS RecordID
FROM ServiceCodes
```

Which seems to have worked! Returning a string like `DF01MOT`. This works across all servers and so I added extra fields producing the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('DF', '01'), ServiceCode) AS RecordID, 'DF' AS Environment 
FROM ServiceCodes
```

This also seems to have worked, except on 1 server. When running the above query on this one server it will now return `DF0DFMO` instead of `DF01MOT`, last 2 chars change in each row depending on `ServiceCode`, adding further fields changes this again such as:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('DF', '01'), ServiceCode) AS RecordID, 'DF' AS Environment, '01' AS SO
FROM ServiceCodes
```

This returns `DF0DF01` for this field in ALL rows.

So why would this be happening? Why is it only on one server? Driver is the same on all servers but is this an issue with the driver? What can I do to get around it?

EDIT: To avoid confusion I have modified the title and tags. This is actually accessing a custom DBMS provided by a third party from with a DTS package in SQL Server Enterprise Manager. I do believe contacting the third party is the only option.

Comment: Is this really SQL Server you are using? If you could provide more information on what you are using to execute and view the results of the queries as well that would be helpful.

Comment: What is the proprietary driver and why do you have to use it? Do the queries work correctly from SSMS using the native drivers?

Comment: Good point, it's actually when creating DTS packages in SQL Server Enterprise manager, so I may have confused matters. It is actually a third party driver for their own modified DB. A native driver isn't going to work simply because it's not a standard DB.

Comment: DTS and Enterprise Manager? Are you using SQL Server 2000? `CONCAT()` was added to SQL Server in version 2012. And I don't understand how a third-party could have modified SQL Server to the point where native drivers don't work? But if you really have such a strange setup I don't think you can expect any help from anyone apart from the vendor.

Comment: It is a terribly strange setup and I was under the presumption that it could only be the vendor issue. But the vendor is a huge company that don't make things easy for us. I might see if they have an updated driver. FYI, it is SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Well the queries you've posted aren't valid in SQL Server 2000 because `CONCAT()` doesn't exist (except as an [ODBC function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630290.aspx) but that has different syntax) so I'm surprised that your queries execute at all. If the proprietary ODBC driver is doing some magic and re-writing queries on the fly then you really have no alternative but to go to the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Having seen your comments, the SQL Server tag is actually a bit misleading here. You are running on a vendor DB using their driver. Clearly their DB supports a `CONCAT` function that only takes two arguments, rather than the SQL Server 2012 function which can take more. That explains your first issue.

As for the other results you are seeing lower down, you'd need to raise this with the vendor. The version of SQL Server you're using for DTS doesn't really have any relevance here.